# Understanding Property of PSD Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

For some reason I can't wrap my mind around several concepts.

I'm reading the proofs:

[The column space of a positive semi-definite matrix A is contained in the column space of A+B?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431454/the-column-space-of-a-positive-semi-definite-matrix-a-is-contained-in-the-column)

[Rank of the sum of two positive semi-definite matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100212/rank-of-the-sum-of-two-positive-semi-definite-matrices)

I can't seem to understand one line. Suppose $X \succeq 0$ is positive semidefinite. Let $v \neq 0$ and suppose $v^{T}Xv=0$. The second and first link say then that $v$ is then in the null space of $X$, meaning $Xv=0$

Why must this be the case?

Thanks.

Comment: I give several proofs that this holds on [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722044/81360)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any positive semidefinite matrix $X$ has a positive semidefinite *square root* $Y$, that is, $Y^2=X$.

> $X$ is symmetric, hence diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis, with nonnegative eigenvalues. Take the diagonal matrix with the square roots of the eigenvalues, in the same basis.

Consequently, $0=v^TXv=v^TY^2v=v^TY^TYv=\|Yv\|^2$ implies $Yv=0$ whence $Xv=Y(Yv)=0$ as well.

Comment: Well, then $-X$ is positive semidefinite, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

On a more fundamental level, if $X$ is positive semidefinite, $(u,v):=u^TXv$ defines a *semi-inner* product. Hence it satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. So, if $(v,v)=0$, then $|u^TXv|=|(u,v)|\le\sqrt{(u,u)(v,v)}=0$ for every vector $u$. Hence $u^TXv$ is identically zero. Since $u$ is arbitrary, $Xv$ must be the zero vector.